# dplyr: random selection using DB-backend

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems like dplyr's `sample_n()` is just implemented for dataframes and not a single SQL-Backend. Is it possible to exploit MySQLs `ORDER BY rand()` using `arrange`? This would be great in combination with dplyr's `head` and would allow similar functionality.

Comment: Is this a feature request? Because then you should be on github, not here.

Comment: @Axeman So far, it is only a question and Github is only for issues. If it turns out that this is a unsupported feature I will make a corresponding feature request on Github.

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/791 You could perhaps make a col via `runif` and sort on that, though.

Comment: @NaN I think you are misinterpreting.  "Issues" on github doesn't always mean "bug".  Issues just means... it's an issue that needs to be discussed/dealt with

Comment: I guess `mtcars %>% filter(row_number() %in% sample(n(), 10))` should work? Normally I would `slice`, but that's not supported for databases.

Comment: @Axeman great solution! It doesn't use ORDER BY rand(), but it is a nice alternative. would you convert this comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to sample `n` rows *without* replacement, one can simply `sample` the row numbers and `filter` on that.

So, if we would like to select 5 random rows from `mtcars`, we can write:

```
filter(mtcars, row_number() %in% sample(n(), 5))
```

That's still a single line, but it is more limited than the normal `sample_n`, since you can't do it with replacement (you can't select a row more than once by filtering). On the plus side, `filter`, `row_number` and `n` should work on all sources.

Note that if the table is grouped, 5 rows will be sampled from each group. If you'd like a fraction instead (like say 50% from each group), you could write:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% sample(n(), round(0.5 * n())))
```

If you'd like to do a weighted sampling, you can directly supply variables to the `prob` argument in `sample`:

```
filter(mtcars, row_number() %in% sample(n(), 5, prob = disp))
```

This samples again 5 rows, but rows with a higher `disp` are more likely to be chosen.